# how to install kaggle_datasets?

Tags: python, kaggle

I'm trying to follow the Kaggle Monet CycleGAN Tutorial and in the first block of code where we are importing the libraries, one of them is kaggle_datasets. I have pip installed Kaggle, but when I try to import kaggle_datasets I get the error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kaggle_datasets'. I tried pip install kaggle_datasets and pip install kaggle-datasets, but neither of them work both return the errors:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kaggle_datasets (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kaggle_datasets

I've been looking and can't find anywhere that shows how to install kaggle_datasets, only how to download specific datasets. The exact line in the tutorial I'm following is:
from kaggle_datasets import KaggleDatasets

here is the link:
https://www.kaggle.com/amyjang/monet-cyclegan-tutorial

Comment: what about this : https://pypi.org/project/kaggledatasets/

Answer (score 1):

The `kaggle_datasets` module can be used in Google Colab and Kaggle Notebook. It's not a part of pip.

If you want to load the dataset on a Kaggle Notebook, follow these steps.

(1) Click on "Add or upload data"
[image]

(2) Search for the dataset that you want
[image]
(3) Expand the "Data box" and load the dataset from the specified path
[image]

If you want to train this AI locally, manually download the photo and Monet datasets from [Monet CycleGAN Tutorial Data](https://www.kaggle.com/code/amyjang/monet-cyclegan-tutorial/data). As you follow the [Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/amyjang/monet-cyclegan-tutorial/notebook), remember to change `str(GCS_PATH + '/monet_tfrec/*.tfrec')` and `str(GCS_PATH + '/photo_tfrec/*.tfrec')` to the paths where you download the datasets. Don't `import kaggle_datasets` because you already have the datasets ready-to-go in your local disk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kaggle, it uses Jupyter conventions so the line should have a `!` before it to run console commands, I believe, so:

```
!pip install kaggle_datasets
```

If that doesn't fix it, is your kernel connected to the internet? That could also be an issue!

Comment: Sometimes, especially in vscode, try using `%pip install kaggle_datasets` if the above solution does not work. Alternatively, use `python -m pip install kaggle_datasets` if using the command line.

Comment: is kaggle_datasets a part of pip? the other answer says no